# How to disable the notification for additional driver

Tags: 12.04, drivers, graphics, jockey

We have chosen to use the Nouveau driver for our PCs with nVidia graphic cards.
Unfortunately every user who gets connected to those PCs get the message "Additional drivers available" ... even if they don't have the right to install it.

How could I disable these notifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can disable the notifications from the startup applications.

First open a terminal and give this command

```
sudo sed 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' -i /etc/xdg/autostart/jockey-gtk.desktop
```

then goto startup applications and unmarked the box.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've found :

```
jockey-text -m free
```

Which will make suggestions only for drivers with "free" license. This solves my case (because drivers suggested aren't free), but doesn't fix the "How to disable all notifications?".

Answer (score 1):

Remove it from the startup applications

copy your `.config` directory from your home to `/etc/skel` directory to apply the settings for the new users you create.

```
sudo cp -R ~/.config /etc/skel/
```

Thus it will not run by itself unless a new user runs it.